# Can't start mysql server on docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, containers, nestjs, nestjs-typeorm

I have a nestJS application that I want to dockerize. I'm a newbie in docker, and I have to do this. In my NestJS application, I'm using mysql database with Typeorm. This mysql is itself coming from a docker image, i.e. I don't have mysql installed on my computer.

I have this docker-compose.yml file:

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: '3.3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=myuser
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mypassword
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=db
      - MYSQL_ROOT_USER=myuser
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root

    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'

volumes:
  mysql:
```

I can run docker-compose up -d and work with the database on my computer. Now, I also have a Dockerfle that I'm trying to write.

I've changed many things over the last 5 hours or so, but in general, it is something like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# Set the working directory to  /usr/src/app
WORKDIR  /usr/src/app

# Copy the package.json and package-lock.json files into the container
COPY package*.json ./

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install curl
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash
RUN apt install -y nodejs

# Install the app dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the app files into the container
COPY . .

# Set environment variables for the MySQL connection
ENV MYSQL_HOST=mysql
ENV MYSQL_USER=myuser
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=mypassword
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=db

# Install the MySQL server
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y mysql-server

# Expose the app's port
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the app in development mode
CMD ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]
```

What I'm trying to do in the Docekerfile above is to create an ubuntu image on the host machine and install curl, node, and mysql respectively so that the app would work with mysql.
I can build this image via docker build -t my-app .

Then, I run the image  docker run my-app and get the following error:

```
[Nest] 29  - 04/02/2023, 7:37:26 PM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16)
```

I have no idea how to deal with this problem.

For reference, this is my app.module.ts file

```
import { Module, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { UsersModule } from './users/users.module';
import { ArtworksModule } from './artworks/artworks.module';
import { User } from './users/entities/user.entity';
import { Artwork } from './artworks/entities/artwork.entity';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { SeedService } from './users/seedService/seedService';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306,
      username: 'myuser',
      password: 'mypassword',
      database: 'db',
      entities: [User, Artwork],
      synchronize: false,
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      logging: true,
    }),
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    UsersModule,
    ArtworksModule,
    AuthModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService, SeedService],
})
export class AppModule implements OnModuleInit {
  constructor(private seedService: SeedService) {}

  async onModuleInit() {
    await this.seedService.seedUsers();
  }
}
```

What is going on in that error? How can I solve this problem? All help is appreciated.

Cheers

EDIT:Now I think I've understood more about the problem, so I'm trying to write a docker-compose-yml file that'll fire up my nestJS app and a mysql image at the same time. First, I've changed my dockerfile to this =>

```
# Use the official Node.js 14 image as the base image
FROM node:14

# Create a working directory for the app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the package.json and package-lock.json files into the container
COPY package*.json ./

# Install app dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the app code into the container
COPY . .

# Expose port 3000 (the port that the app listens on)
EXPOSE 3000

# Specify the command to run when the container starts
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start:prod" ]
```

Then wrote this docker-compose.yml file =>

```
services:
  app:
    build: .
    command: npm run start:prod
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=mysql
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - DB_USER=myuser
      - DB_PASSWORD=mypassword
      - DB_NAME=db
    depends_on:
      - mysql

  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=myuser
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mypassword
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=db
      - MYSQL_ROOT_USER=myuser
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  mysql:

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
```

Now when I run sudo docker-compose up on bash (without sudo it gives permission denied error), I get the following error

```
my-app-1    | [Nest] 19  - 04/03/2023, 8:28:03 AM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
my-app-1    | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
my-app-1    |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1159:16)
my-app-1    | [Nest] 19  - 04/03/2023, 8:28:06 AM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (2)...
my-app-1    | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
my-app-1    |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1159:16)
```

As I see it, it can't connect to the database. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this issue?

EDIT 2: Per comments, I've tinkered a bit more. These are my findings:

The DB_HOST value doesn't seem to matter.

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: '3.3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=localhost
      - MYSQL_ROOT_USER=myuser
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root

    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'

volumes:
  mysql:
```

I can change this value to anything I want and this script will work on my local machine.

Again, this is my app.module.ts file =>

```
import { Module, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { UsersModule } from './users/users.module';
import { ArtworksModule } from './artworks/artworks.module';
import { User } from './users/entities/user.entity';
import { Artwork } from './artworks/entities/artwork.entity';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { SeedService } from './users/seedService/seedService';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      port: 3306,
      username: 'myuser',
      password: 'mypassword',
      database: 'db',
      entities: [User, Artwork],
      synchronize: false,
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      logging: true,
    }),
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    UsersModule,
    ArtworksModule,
    AuthModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService, SeedService],
})
export class AppModule implements OnModuleInit {
  constructor(private seedService: SeedService) {}

  async onModuleInit() {
    await this.seedService.seedUsers();
  }
}
```

As I'm trying to dockerize this app so that it will run on a machine that has only Docker installed, I'm trying to change the docker-compose.yml file as such =>

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    command: npm run start:prod
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=localhost
      - DB_PORT=3306

    depends_on:
      - mysql

  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_USER=myuser
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root

    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'

volumes:
  mysql:

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
```

This results in two different behavior: I can't run docker-compose up anymore, it gives the following error =>

```
  => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:14                                                     1.4s
 => [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/node:14@sha256:a97048059988c65f974b37dfe25a44327069a0f4f81133624871de0063b98  0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load build context                                                                        0.1s
 => => transferring context: 402.84kB                                                                          0.0s
------
 > [internal] load build context:
------
failed to solve: error from sender: open /home/sirius/coding/my-app/mysql/#innodb_redo: permission denied
```

I'm using fish terminal, so for some reason I need to change to bash to run sudo docker-compose up which in turn gives the following error that signifies there's a problem in connecting to the database=>

```
e dependencies initialized +0ms
budapest-icf-recruitment-backend-app-1    | [Nest] 19  - 04/03/2023, 9:26:34 AM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
budapest-icf-recruitment-backend-app-1    | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
budapest-icf-recruitment-backend-app-1    |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1159:16)
budapest-icf-recruitment-backend-app-1    | [Nest] 19  - 04/03/2023, 9:26:37 AM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (2)...
budapest-icf-recruitment-backend-app-1    | Error: connect ECONN
```

I'm like, really stuck.

Comment: Why do you try to run the MySQL server within any other container? Use a seperate one

Comment: Also, if you **insist** of putting everything into one container, you should at least check whether installing the MySQL server also starts it

Comment: mysql is a background server process. Its not running in your container and attempts to make it do so are quite involved. Stick with your original docker-compose. It was very easy to make wasn't it :-), that's a good sign.

Comment: Use A non-local IP to connect MySQL. Use real Valid IP address of your system.

Comment: Thanks for your commenst! Now I've understood a bit more about the process and changed my course of actions a bit. I'll edit the question accordingly as my problem is now different :)

Comment: The docker-compose.yml script loooks completely invalid. It should not contain any `Dockerfile`  syntax

Comment: can you elaborate on how can I make the yml file valid?

Comment: The first docker-compose.yml you've posted contains valid syntax, the second one does not

Comment: Thanks for pointing, I realized I've pasted the wrong contents, fixed it. Now my problem is I can't connect to the database. It seems to be running, but can't connect => my-app-1    | [Nest] 19  - 04/03/2023, 8:28:03 AM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
my-app-1    | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
my-app-1    |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1159:16)
my-app-1    | [Nest] 19  - 04/03/2023, 8:28:06 AM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (2)...

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Why do you try to connect to `localhost`  in your code when you have set another host (and other configuration settings) through the `DB_`  environment variables in the `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: Usually, a Docker container is accessible through its name, not through `localhost`

Comment: @NicoHaase I've changed my edits, the answer to your question is just my rookieness I guess. I'm confused, this shouldn't be that difficult. I just want to dockerize a nestJs application that will use mysql...

Comment: Please don't edit your question when you've resolved your problem. Post an answer instead

Answer (score 0):

Fixed all problems by changing the docker-compose.yml file like so =>

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    image: my-app
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    command: npm run start:dev
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=mysql
      - DB_PORT=3306

    depends_on:
      - mysql

  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_USER=myuser
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root

    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'

volumes:
  mysql:

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
```

and this is my Dockerfile =>

```
# Use the official Node.js 14 image as the base image
FROM node:14

# Create a working directory for the app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the package.json and package-lock.json files into the container
COPY package*.json ./

# Install app dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the app code into the container
COPY . .

# Expose port 3000 (the port that the app listens on)
EXPOSE 3000

# Specify the command to run when the container starts
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start:dev" ]
```